# represent "and" "or" "not" in GNU prolog

Tags: prolog, gnu

I am new to prolog, we are asking to write a prolog program of the question below:

If the unicorn is mythical, then it is immortal, but if it is not mythical, then it is a mortal mammal. If the unicorn is either immortal or a mammal, then it is horned. The unicorn is magical if it is horned.

code1:

```
unicorn(immortal):- unicorn(mythical).
(unicorn(immortal), unicorn(mammal)):- unicorn(mythical).
unicorn(horned):- (unicorn(immortal); unicorn(mammal)).
unicorn(magical):- unicorn(horned).
```

code2:

```
unicorn(immortal):- unicorn(mythical).
unicorn(mythical):- unicorn(mammal).
unicorn(mythical):- unicorn(immortal).
unicorn(horned):- unicorn(immortal).
unicorn(horned):- unicorn(mammal).
unicorn(magical):- unicorn(horned).
```

What we need to prove is to prove that unicorn is magical. Here are some attempts of mine, I compiled them successfully on linux but when I run the command:

```
?- unicorn(magical).
```

They both returned false.
 I guess I do not know how to implement "not", "and" or "or" in prolog, and I could not find any examples on them. Please let me know what I did wrong. Thanks!

Update:
After read the comments, I updated mine like this:

```
isimmortal(unicorn):- ismythical(unicorn).
ismammal(unicorn):- \+ ismythical(unicorn).
ishorned(unicorn):- isimmortal(unicorn); ismammal(unicorn).
ismagical(unicorn):- ishorned(unicorn).
```

This code through me an exception, which is:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,ismythical/1),isimmortal/1)
```

I do not know what is wrong with it.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. If you query `?-unicorn(magical).` the second program loops forever... Can you provide some better explanation and expected results?

Comment: `(unicorn(immortal), unicorn(mammal)):- unicorn(mythical).` isn't valid Prolog syntax.

Comment: I would run the logic differently and define `is_mortal`, `is_mythical`, `is_horned` and `is_mammal`. So, for example, `is_horned(unicorn) :- is_mythical(unicorn) ; is_mammal(unicorn).`. Anything that doesn't succeed in Prolog will fail. So you should focus on what is true, not on negatives where possible. In other words, try not to define logic that says, *X is not something if X is not this and X is not that*. It's problematic. But you can have: `is_mortal(unicorn) :- \+ is_mythical(unicorn).` and `is_mammal(unicorn) :- \+ is_mythical(unicorn).` since both of these are true.

Comment: @damianodamiano  am trying to prove that unicorn is magical from all the statements. hmmm I dont understand why the second one loop forever?

Comment: @lurker I actually did something like this, but what I did was -`ismortal(unicorn, mortal)` I guess that is where I messed up? Also, if I understand you correctly,  I should not focus on syntax? like try to interpret something like `not A implies B and C` ?

Comment: You should change the rapresentation of the knowledge base, as suggested in lurker's comment. Then you need to declare some predicates like `isMythical(unicorn).` and `isMammal(unicorn).` in order to make your program work.

Comment: @damianodamiano hmmm I updated my code in my problem statement. But in the problem, it did not have any facts like that. So I think I cannot declare `isMythical(unicorn).` or anything like that

Comment: `ismortal(unicorn, mortal)` is redundant. Why would you need the `mortal` argument for a fact that says `ismortal`? That would be like saying, `istrue(foo, true)`. Now you could say, `life_expectancy(unicorn, mortal)` and `life_expectancy(dog, mortal)`. That would make more sense. I thought you were trying to establish a rule that says if a creature is not mythical then it is mortal. Thus a rule, `is_mortal(X) :- \+ mythical(X).`.

Comment: With Prolog, you want to assert what is true. Anything that's false should fail because it cannot be proven due to lack of asserted facts or rules that make it provable. This is unlike other languages where you literally return true or false for a boolean result. That's not how Prolog is intended to work.

Comment: @lurker I modified my code and posted my new one above in the question statement. I think it should work, but it did not, do you know why?

Comment: It says `ismythical/1` does not exist. You haven't defined any facts or rules for `ismythival/1` that take one argument.

Comment: @lurker hmmmm but in the problem, it did not include any facts though, like, it did not say anything like " unicorn is mythical" or anything like that.

Comment: You need to start somewhere with some kind of facts from which rules derive. `ismythical(unicorn)` you are taking as a fundamental known fact, but you haven't asserted it. How is Prolog supposed to know it's true if it's not asserted?

Comment: @lurker should I just write two programs that one assume unicorn is mythical and the other assume it is not? By the way, thank you for all the explanations!

Comment: You wouldn't need two programs. Declare `ismythical` as dynamic (`:- dynamic(ismythical/1).`) then assert or retract the fact `ismythical(unicorn)`.